# Can French/British be used as plural nouns?

Tags: nouns, irregular-plurals

Neither *British* nor *French* can be used as a singular noun. For example, (a) is ungrammatical.

> a. *A French/British is dancing.

Although *the French*/*British* can mean 'French/British people' collectively, *French*/*British* is usually analyzed as adjectives. For example, (b) is grammatical and natural English.

> b. The French/British are struggling.

Can *British* and *French* be used as plural nouns, meaning 'British people' and 'French people', respectively, **outside the construction *The French*/*British***?

For example, is (c) grammatical and natural? How about (d)?

> c. A lot of French/British are dancing.
>
> d. Several French/British are dancing.

Comment: If "French" / "British" are interpreted as "French / English  people", they can hardly be nouns.

Comment: @BillJ I've just edited it.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Does 'The French are...' or 'The Chinese are...' sound "old-fashioned and stiff" to you?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey But 'The French' or 'The Chinese' as collectively referring to the whole people is a pretty standard way of expressing the idea.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Although I'd find 'a Chinese' derogatory.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey As for the use of 'French' as a plural noun without 'the', here's a quote from the Telegraph: _In an unlikely protest, hundreds of French have taken to the streets to demand the opening of a McDonald's in their town._

Comment: @MichaelHarvey So do you think c and d are unacceptable?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey The question is not about whether a sentence is "a stupid generalization." Even stupid generalizations can be well-formed English.

Comment: "The British are coming!  The British are coming!"

Answer (score 1):

No, *French* and *British* cannot be used as plural nouns. Generally, you cannot use an adjective of nationality as a plural noun if there is already a different noun for a single person of that nationality.

So for example, you cannot say:

> Three Spanish were ...
> Three Polish were ...
> Three Turkish were ...,

because you would use the words *Spaniards, Poles,* and *Turks*, instead.
You can, however, say

> Three Japanese were ...
> Three Portuguese were ...,

because there are no separate nouns for people of these nationalities.
See [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?smoothing=3&corpus=26&year_start=1800&content=Briton%2C+Brit&year_end=2019&direct_url=t1%3B%2CBriton%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CBrit%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2CBriton%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CBrit%3B%2Cc0).

Historically, the noun for British people was [*Briton*](https://www.lexico.com/definition/briton) and for French people was [*Frenchman*](https://www.lexico.com/definition/frenchman).  Today, you could still use *Briton*, but you might want to use [*Brit*](https://www.lexico.com/definition/brit) instead, especially if you're speaking informally.

Unfortunately, *Frenchman* is not gender-neutral, and so probably should not be used today. It's possible that *French* will eventually replace *Frenchmen* as an acceptable plural noun, but it hasn't yet. The best current alternative may be

> Three of the French were ...

which I don't particularly like, but which is much better than [*Frenchies*](https://www.lexico.com/definition/frenchy), which is often derogatory.

Comment: I'd point out that there's also "Englishman," parallel to Frenchman in your discussion.  It's much more common than "Briton," I think.  Unlike "Briton," it excludes the Scots and Welsh, but they have their own terms.

Answer (score 0):

The words “**British**” and “**French**” can be

(1) nominalised adjectives (compare “The **poor** are revolting.” See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominalized_adjective), which take a plural verb form or

(2) as common adjectives (a)predicatively: “He is French/British”, and (b) attributively: “They are French wines/British cheeses.”

Adjectives are not inflected, thus all nominalised adjectives act as uncountable nouns, thus **a** *French* and **a** *British* are not possible.

This differs from the words **American** and **German**, etc., in which the words **American** and **German** may act as

(1) pure nouns - "Americans/Germans like beer" and "An American/German was elected," or

(2) adjectives - "I like American/German beer" and "The beer was American/German"

But not as nominalised adjectives:

Compare

*The poor **like** food.*

*A poor **like** food.* is wrong

*The/An American **likes** food.* Here, American is clearly singular.

but

*The/An American **like** food."* is wrong.

Comment: I'm not asking about 'American' or 'German'. I'm only asking about 'French' and 'British'. Please edit out the irrelevant portion. Also, the only clue in your answer is "all nominalised adjectives act as uncountable nouns", which I guess means that you're saying that (c) and (d) are not possible, are you?

Comment: @listenevea - it would be easier for you to ignore the points that you find irrelevant. "*all nominalised adjectives act as uncountable nouns*" is not a 'clue'; It is an explanation of why "He is **a** British" cannot be correct.

Comment: Well, I have laid out at the outset that (a) doesn't work for me. So I cannot understand why you would want to explain why (a) or "He is a British" doesn't work. Let me ask you again. Are you saying that (c) and (d) don't work? If so, are you saying that that's because "all nominalised adjectives act as uncountable nouns"?

Comment: A quite remarkable misunderstanding... No, I am not 'saying that (c) and (d) don't work.' I was attempting to have you to understand the principle behind your question.

Comment: Please note the general question at the end and that (c) and (d) are example sentences of the question. AFAIK, nowhere in your answer did you address the general question at all, or example sentence (c) or (d). The only thing that I think touches on the general question is "all nominalised adjectives act as uncountable nouns", because you classify _British_ and _French_ in (c) and (d) as "nominalised adjectives". Since they "act as uncountable nouns", you're essentially saying (c) and (d) are wrong, which you just denied in the comment. You lost me.